# Как сделать окно активным, используя метод AppActivate()?

Tags: powershell

Как сделать окно активным, используя метод `AppActivate()`? (Как правильно написать?)

Насколько я знаю, есть два способа (?) по заголовку окна и ID процесса. По заголовку окна не подходит, т.к. он постоянно меняется.

Так же меня интересует, как узнать ID нужного процесса и куда его нужно записать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день.
Вам необходимо сначала узнать ID процесса, а потом активировать окно приложения.
Эту тему уже обсуждали, к примеру вот [тут.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679178/appactivate-working-inconsistently-in-powershell)

Так получается ID процесса по имени.

```
$excelpid = (Get-Process excel).ID
```

[Описание модуля Get-Process.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Process?view=powershell-5.1) Там можете посмотреть по каким параметрам вам удобнее найти ID процесса.

Так можно активировать

```
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($excelpid)
```